# Normal And UpsideDown Triangle of stars in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a upsidedown triangle and a normal triangle and it should look like this:

```
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *          
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

I created something but I get 5 new lines and than the other triangle:

```
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *





     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

Here is the C++ code , Hope someone can resolve my issue :

```
int n,i,j;

cout<<"Give the Number N of Stars ";
cin>>n;

for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{    
    for(j=1;j<=i-1;j++)
        cout<<" ";
     for(j=i;j<=n-i+1;j++)
        cout<<"*";
     cout<<"\n";
}

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{    
    for(j=i;j<=n-1;j++)
        cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-n;j++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do it using two for loops? And It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.

Comment: Pick some arbitrary N and go through it by hand, line-by-line to see what you get when you draw it out. (I'll give you a hint, the bounds in your for loops aren't quite what you think they are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop is making `i` go from `1` to `n` (which means `n` rows), but there are less than `n` rows since each row, the number of stars decreases by 2, not 1. The extra lines are the result of this. There are no stars in the extra lines because in this loop:

```
for(j=i;j<=n-i+1;j++)
    cout<<"*";
```

once `i` exceeds half the size of `n`, the loop will not print any stars, since the initial value of `j` is greater than the terminating condition for `j`.

Comment: don't know if I deserve that, but glad to help